# HttpListener behaves differently on different machines

Tags: c#, concurrency, httplistener

I have been playing around with the HttpListener class lately and testing some stuff, I finally wrote this code (which is totally experimental and is not intended for production rather educational purpose only)

```
 private static async Task ProcessRequestContext(HttpListenerContext ctx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Context Process call");
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        Stream sOut = ctx.Response.OutputStream;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("H3ll0 w0rld!");
        ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = data.Length;
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");

        sOut.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        sOut.Flush();
        sOut.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Responded @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private static async Task listener()
    {
        HttpListener http = new HttpListener();
        http.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");

        http.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Started on http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
        while (true)
        {
            var context = await http.GetContextAsync();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ProcessRequestContext(context); });


        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting http server");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { listener(); });
        Console.WriteLine("Started the Listener");
        Thread.Sleep(-1);
    }
```

The code is pretty straight forward and uncomplicated, the purpose of the code is to process Http requests concurrently and it actually does work on my PC which has an i7-4790K processor and running Windows 10 Version 1709.

This is the console output when browsing the link "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" in a browser two times concurrently :

```
Starting http server
Started the Listener
Started on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
New Context Process call
New Context Process call
Responded @ 06-Feb-18 3:40:45 PM
Responded @ 06-Feb-18 3:40:45 PM
```

This means that the both requests have been processed concurrently as the both responses were sent at the same time.

However running the exact same code on my laptop with an i5-6200U gives a surprisingly different results

which are :

```
Starting http server
Started the Listener
Started on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
New Context Process call
Responded @ 06-Feb-18 3:42:01 PM
New Context Process call
Responded @ 06-Feb-18 3:42:06 PM
```

Which shows that the requests have not been processed concurrently and this was also obviously noticeable in the browser with a 5 seconds delay between the two responses even though the two requests were made at the same time.

I have also tried to investigate this and discovered that on my laptop "http.GetContextAsync();" won't give me the new request's context until I finish processing the one before and close its stream while on my PC it just passes me the new request context as soon as a new request has been made by the browser.

I have succeed to process requests concurrently on my laptop too using "BeginGetContext/EndGetContext", but I would like to understand and know why the code I wrote didn't behave on my laptop as same as it did on my PC.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like what youd get from a single thread vs multi thread..

Comment: I agree that it looks like multi vs single but what's the thing that's making GetContextAsync to return contexts concurrently on the PC and wait for the last context to be closed on the laptop

Comment: You listed details of the desktop.  Whats the laptop?

Comment: I actually listed the laptop's too, it has an i5-6200U processor and 8GBs of RAM.

Comment: Your desktop has more cores.. Id suggest for whatever reason your laptop just lined them up one after the other..

Comment: I tried running the code in a virtual machine on the PC with only 1 core and the code seems to work fine. I also tried the program on another laptop with 4 cores and 8 threads which is the i7-6700HQ and the problem still exists on the laptop, I don't know if it has to do something with mobile processors that are used in laptops since the code is working on two different PCs and not working on two different laptops.